# Update minutes value to 0 for unmatched data with having keeping one data as it is

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

[image]

Need to update some data based on specific column unmatched & keeping one data as it is

Also need to take care of performance as this is for huge data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  For your example:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by therapyadmissionid, units, totalminutes order by documentstartdate) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set units = 0,
        totalminutes = 0
    where seqnum > 1;
```

I should note that the need to do this suggests that you have a flaw in your data model.  The `units` and `totalminutes` should probably be stored in another table.